# Pinchin doesn't calll using Hammer library

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I have downloaded Hammers.js version-1.0.10 i have many try to call 'pinch in' function from js file but it can't execute. i think in library problem i have download other but same problem occurs.Other function like Touch,swipe, drag all works only pinch is not working[not calling].
If any one know than tell me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a closer look at that version now and events for "pinch", "pinchin", "pinchout" and "transform" should all be being fired.

If you don't have a minified version, you can see this at line 1217

```
inst.trigger('pinch', ev);
inst.trigger('pinch'+ ((ev.scale < 1) ? 'in' : 'out'), ev);
```

"transform" and "pinch" are the more general events. You can use the event data to determine whether or not it is in or out.

As I first suggested, you can use the "transform" event. The pinch zoom example that shipped with version 1.0.10 also used the transform event:

```
hammertime.on('touch drag transform', function(ev) {
    switch(ev.type) {
        case 'touch':
            last_scale = scale;
            last_rotation = rotation;
            break;

        case 'drag':
            posX = ev.gesture.deltaX;
            posY = ev.gesture.deltaY;
            break;

        case 'transform':
            rotation = last_rotation + ev.gesture.rotation;
            scale = Math.max(1, Math.min(last_scale * ev.gesture.scale, 10));
            break;
    }

    // transform!
    var transform =
            "translate3d("+posX+"px,"+posY+"px, 0) " +
            "scale3d("+scale+","+scale+", 0) " +
            "rotate("+rotation+"deg) ";

    rect.style.transform = transform;
    rect.style.oTransform = transform;
    rect.style.msTransform = transform;
    rect.style.mozTransform = transform;
    rect.style.webkitTransform = transform;
});
```

The firing of pinchin/out events is in a conditional for the transform_min_scale value being met. When you create your hammer elements, try setting transform_min_scale to something like -1.

Comment: Yep,
Pinch not work but using Transform i have completed work

Comment: I'm glad you got it working, though I fear I haven't really answered your question. I've taken a closer look and I can't see a reason why looking at pinch events wouldn't work as well.

If you go to github and find your release version, you'll find a pinch zoom example. This would have given you my solution in telling you to use the transform event, but as for why pinch doesn't work, I am at a loss.

Comment: Yes, I am also finding but i finding that we have to change in Hammer.js library for working pinch event. because in Library the pinch is not available it's available as form of transform.

Comment: Thanks for your source-code reference!! it helped me solve my problem.... I was trying to trigger something on `pinchin` assuming that meant the effect is what you get natively by "pinching in" , but it is the physical motion of one's fingers pinching together!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure aout the specific version. In 2.0.2 pinch is disabled by default. Enable it using something like:

```
mc.get('pinch').set({enable: true})
```

Comment: Oh my god, I searched about 2 hours for this solution. Thank you! Where did you get this information?